# Conditions guaranteeing differentiability in R^2

Tags: multivariable-calculus

First time questioner here!

I'm finding conflicting information about what conditions will guarantee differentiability of functions of two variables. Among the different sources I'm seeing three main alternatives:

1. Differentiability at a point is guaranteed if the partial derivatives **are continuous at the point**.
2. Differentiability at a point is guaranteed if the partial derivatives **exist in a neighbourhood of the point and are continuous at the point**.
3. Differentiability at a point is guaranteed if the partial derivatives **are continuous in a neighbourhood of the point.**"

I've seen a proof for (3) which is convincing. However, being the weakest of the three alternatives, it doesn't help determine if (1) or (2) are true/false.

If any knows sources which confirm any of these with proofs, and/or counterexamples for any which are false, that would be great!

EDIT:  The question was closed for lack of details or clarity, so I made some edits, but I'm not sure exactly which part was deemed unclear. If someone thinks the question is still unclear, perhaps you could comment and ask me for the information which is missing?

Comment: Welcome to Mathemtics Stack Exchange! I think you should include where you are stuck adapting the proof of 3 to 2.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, 1 and 2 are equivalent if the partial derivatives are not only defined at a single point (then they are continuous at this single point, but do not exist in a neighbourhood of the point). So, existence in a neighbourhood of the point cannot be dropped, meaning 1 is wrong. 2 only gives us that the total derivative at the point exists. Whereas 3 implies that the total derivative exists for this neighbourhood. If you have seen a proof for 3, it should be easy to adapt for 2. Feel free to include the proof in your question and ask for anything unclear.